# How to compute Basic Authorization header from username and password

Tags: node.js, http, authentication

I have `username` and `password` and I want to compute `Authorization` header for HTTP Basic Auth. Computed header looks like this: `'Basic xyz123xxx'`. Is there a node package in npm that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to encode the string for use in the header.

```
Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString("base64")
```

Comment: You missed "Basic " prefix I gess

Comment: 'Basic ' prefix shouldn't be included in the argument to `Buffer`. You would combine the result of `Buffer` with the 'Basic ' prefix.